# Create n new columns by n distinct groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table, and would like to sum y twice grouping the *first* time by g1 and the *second* time by g2.

Usually I would just chain the calculations together, but I would like to be able to do the grouped sum *n* different times by *n* groups.

```
library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(
    g1 = c("a", "b"),
    g2 = c("a", "a"),
    y = c(3,5)
  )

new_cols <- paste0("sum_by_", c("g1", "g2"))
group_cols <- c("g1", "g2")

# Supplying cols to by like this groups by g1 AND g2, when in reality I want it to 
# take g1 the first time and g2 the second time. 
DT[, paste(new_cols) := lapply(rep(y, length(new_cols)), sum),
   by = .(group_cols)][]
```

this gives me:

```
#    g1 g2 y sum_by_g1 sum_by_g2
# 1:  a  a 3         3         3
# 2:  b  a 5         5         5
```

when I actually want:

```
#    g1 g2 y sum_by_g1 sum_by_g2
# 1:  a  a 3         3         8
# 2:  b  a 5         5         8
```

Is there any slick data.table way to do this? Something *like* supplying .SD to by (this in itself doesn't seem to work)?

### Edit: Changed y from c(1,1) to c(3,5)

Edit Rationale: Actual and desired outputs while y = c(1,1) gave the impression that I wanted to count the observations in each group, when I actually want to sum(y) for each group.

Comment: @akrun because sum_by_g2 for second one is the sum of y for group g2 == "a".

(length() is just there to give y to lapply the correct number of times. Maybe this too is bad form?)

Comment: I realize your desired result is in a _wide_ format, but I just want to mention another item in the `data.table` tool box: `groupingsets`, which gives the answer in a _long_ format. Here we could do something like `groupingsets(DT, j = sum(y), by = c("g1", "g2"), sets = list("g1", "g2"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping should be separate as `a a` and `a b` are regarded as unique elements thus, there is only a single observation per group

```
for(i in seq_along(group_cols)) DT[, (new_cols[i]) := sum(y), by = c(group_cols[i])]
```

-output

```
DT
   g1 g2 y sum_by_g1 sum_by_g2
1:  a  a 3         3         8
2:  b  a 5         5         8
```

Comment: Using this for( i in seq_along()) solves my problem perfectly. Only thing is that my desired vs actual example outputs were ambiguous to whether I wanted the sum or the number of rows by group. I have edited my input data to try make this more clear.

Comment: @gvan Your desired shows both `sum` i.e. 3 5 and 8 8

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Reduce` like below

```
> Reduce(function(dt, g) dt[, paste0("sum_by_", g) := .N, g], list(DT, "g1", "g2"))[]
   g1 g2 y sum_by_g1 sum_by_g2
1:  a  a 1         1         2
2:  b  a 1         1         2
```

or

```
> Reduce(function(dt, g) dt[, paste0("sum_by_", g) := .N, g], c("g1", "g2"),init = DT)[]
   g1 g2 y sum_by_g1 sum_by_g2
1:  a  a 1         1         2
2:  b  a 1         1         2
```